# Is it possible to use std::conditional in a CUDA kernel?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm looking to template a CUDA kernel. Neither [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22std::conditional%22+cuda), not [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%22std%3A%3Aconditional%22+cuda%22) were particularly forthcoming. Within this kernel, I would like to have a typedef that is dependent on the typename. I tried the following (assuming/hoping) it would work similarly to C++ but it didn't.

```
#include <type_traits>  // for std::conditional. Not sure if it's necessary
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>

template <typename fType>
__global__ void DummyKernel() {
    typedef std::conditional<sizeof(fType) == sizeof(double), cuDoubleComplex, cuFloatComplex>::type cfType;
}
```

This produces the error

```
nontype "std::conditional<_Test, _Ty1, _Ty2>::type [with _Test=<expression>, _Ty1=cuDoubleComplex, _Ty2=cuFloatComplex]" is not a type name
```

Is there a way to do what I want? I'm using CUDA 5.5 and VS2012.

Comment: You're missing the `typename` keyword after the `typedef`.

Comment: @catscradle I was about to say that I'm using VS and it doesn't comply with the standard, when I realized that the Nvidia compiler is separate. I have to break my stupid lazy habits. I'll accept this as the answer if posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::conditional` depends on a template parameter `fType`, so you must put the `typename` keyword after the `typedef`.

Comment: Can you use `std::conditional` at all in a CUDA kernel?

Comment: @JackOLantern I have no idea. I assumed from OP's comment that it worked for him...

Comment: @JackOLantern All of the `std::conditional`'s code is in the header, so what is there to compile?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for those who want to achieve the same result without relying on C++11 (using C++11 with CUDA may not be as straightforward for now), you can use [Boost MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) instead:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/conditional.hpp>

template <typename fType>
__global__ void DummyKernel() {
    typedef typename boost::conditional<sizeof(fType) == sizeof(double), cuDoubleComplex, cuFloatComplex>::type cfType;
// Which is an equivalent of:
// typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::mpl::bool_<sizeof(fType) == sizeof(double)>, cuDoubleComplex, cuFloatComplex>::type cfType;

    // Quick size check
    printf("size = %u\n", sizeof (cfType));
}
```

Compilation is simply (adapt to your CUDA architecture):

```
nvcc test.cu -o test -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30
```

Then, you get:

```
DummyKernel<float>  ---> size = 8
DummyKernel<double> ---> size = 16
```

Tested with CUDA 5.5 and Boost 1.55 on Arch Linux.